# pass no id, but only parameters with Rails path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

With my settings, I have the following routes

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

Now, in my corresponding index.html.haml view under app/views... etc, I have a link looking like this,

```
 %th#name_header= link_to "List Names", user_path( ...
```

Now, I'd like to define that link, so that I can call the index action, that is, I come back to the same page, with different settings

Comment: What do you mean "specifying the format solely"?

Comment: I reformulated the question. I just want to come back to the same page, but change the settings by calling the index method of the corresponding controller

Answer (score 1):

The index action is mapped to `users_path`, not `user_path` - that's the show action and requires an `:id` parameter with this setup. To link to the index action with a format (e.g. javascript), use

```
users_path(:format => "js")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to link to the users index page, so you have to use `users_path` (note *plural*):

```
= link_to "List Names", users_path
```

You can then of course pass `users_path` any of the parameters you'd like.